# Window is freezing

Tags: c++, opengl

This runs well in Linux but on Windows the window stops responding and mouse goes in waiting cursor. What am I missing?

```
// initialization
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE);
glutInitWindowSize(1024, 768);
glutCreateWindow("GL Window");
glutTimerFunc(2, update, 0);
glutDisplayFunc(display);
glutMainLoop();
// ...
fflush(stdout);

// update rate
void update(int value)
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(250, update, 0);
}

// loop
while(true)
{
    display()
    {
        drawing(5);
        glutSwapBuffers();
    }
}

// drawing
void drawing(unsigned int sides)
{
    if (sides < 3) return;
    const float step = (2 * PI) / static_cast<float>(sides);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sides; ++i)
    {
        glVertex2f(cos(i * step), sin(i * step));
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

Comment: What happens when you `glFlush()` at the end of your `drawing()` function? Have you broken into a debugger to test this and see if it's hanging somewhere inside _your_ code?

Comment: no difference. It doesn't hang somewhere. As I said it's running well in linux.

Comment: I think Qix meant try stepping through it in Windows to see where it hangs/freezes

Comment: From experience, graphics driver bugs are **_mystical_** at best. Hope that this isn't one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for comment from Alex and Qix. 
I found out I'm running the opengl draw function in a loop. Removing the loop solved the issue.
Still wondering why in Linux it was working though ?